# Stop receiving events from destroyed child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent where I can dynamically add child components into.

When child component is added in mount I register a listener for an event

```
EventBus.$on('content-type-saving', function() {
    logic here...
}
```

Problem is when that component is deleted in the parent by removing it from the array of child components, that even still fires and code inside of it is run.

How can I prevent this from happening? I tried this

```
    beforeDestroy() {
      //do something before destroying vue instance
        EventBus.$off('content-type-saving')
    }
```

but that turned off that event for all other child components as well so those that were still live would not do logic stuff anymore because I turned off event in destroyed child component.

I thought if I turned off an event it would only affect listening for that event for that child component and not turn the event for all child components.

How can I stop destroyed components from reacting on events?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

When you call `$off` with just the name of the event, [*all* listeners are removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off) for the event specified.

Instead, you want to remove the event only for the component that is listening. your component should look something like this:

```
const component = {
  methods:{
    listener(){
      //do something on event
    }
  },
  created(){
    EventBus.$on('content-type-saving', this.listener)
  },
  beforeDestroy(){
    EventBus.$off('content-type-saving', this.listener)
  }
}
```

This will remove only the specific listener for the current component.

Comment: Best answer for me :) Thumbs up !

Comment: @Bert do i have to use same method for destroying EventBus?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed I've never destroyed an event bus; if you are using one, you typically need it for the life of the app. Otherwise, I would expect normal garbage collection to take care of it.

Comment: worth noting here that when your listener has a param you can just use `listener(myParam) {...}` in the methods as it get passed through from the event bus

Answer (score 2):

another solution without creating component method

```
mounted(){
  const listener = () => {
    // heavy logic
  };

  EventBus.$on('content-type-saving', listener);

  this.$once("hook:beforeDestroy", () => {
     EventBus.$off('content-type-saving', listener);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you are rendering the components with some kind of loop that gives them some sort of index. Just off the top of my head, what you could do is push the index to an array and then in your eventBus.$on function you would test to see if the index of that component exists in the array(on the parent component) and fire the logic if it doesn't.

```
EventBus.$emit('content-type-saving', index);

EventBus.$on('content-type-saving', function(index) {
    if(this.deletedComponentArray.indexOf(index) == -1){
        //execute logic
    }
}
```

that's just one way to skin a cat. I'm sure there are other ways of doing it as well.